# R: argument is not a character vector "enc2utf8(path)"

Tags: r, tidyverse

I cannot understand what's going on. I think this is related to the updating of R that I did before this problem occured. After running the code below I get an error message "Error in enc2utf8(path) : argument is not a character vector"

My data comes from an ordinary csv file.

```
Mydata <- read_csv(Mydata, col_names = c(
    "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", 
    "var5", "var6", "var7")) %>% 
  mutate(var7 = factor(var7))
```

Comment: This bit: `Mydata <- read_csv(Mydata,...)` is confusing. The first argument to `read_csv()` should be a file path, eg "folder/filename.csv". `Mydata` sounds like the name of a data frame, indeed you're assigning the result to the same name. Are you sure you gave `read_csv()` a file path?

Comment: Omg I was dum. That was the issue. Thanks